# SCR reverse current during switch off

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, scr

In the figure below is shown the dynamic behavior of an SCR in terms of its current during switch off. 
I'm interested in **calculating** the maximum reverse current (iR in the plot).
The parameters that I know are the common one that datasheet usually report: Vrrm, Irrm, trr..

What I don't know is actually Qrr that would have been useful.

[image: Iak of an SCR during switch off process]

Comment: Parameter descriptions are here: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/ea/24/b1/42/31/ca/4d/66/CD00183570.pdf/files/CD00183570.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00183570.pdf  If that doesn't help, we need a more specific question.

Comment: @Mattman944 I hope that now it's more clear!

Comment: You can not calculate that. If the reverse recovery parameters can not be obtained from the manufacturer, the device is not suitable for applications where that matters.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I suspected that. Though what I noted is that its magnitude is proportional to diR/dt  so probably I can derive some coefficient from experimental evaluations? My final purpose is to characterize a specific SCR device

Comment: With the proper equipment, you can test any given device to determine the reverse recovery characteristics, but I don't think you can use the characteristics of one device to accurately predict the characteristics of a different device.